# Report on SkillUser Object

Tags: liveagent

We have LiveAgent enabled and have configured Skills and assigned Skills to Users. We are able to extract SkillUser object from data loader, however not able to create a report from reporting tab.

Opened a case with salesforce but was pointed to the following idea. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gOxvAAE

I'm not sure the above idea covers what we are looking for. I suspect we need work.com, any direction would be greatly appreciated.